# Error reporting service (ACRA) use with Fragment. Possible?

Tags: android, android-fragments, acra

I am developing an app using `Fragments` and I want to implement an error reporting service in to it. I found this project called `ACRA` but it requires to be extended with Application class. Does anyone know if it is possible to implement `ACRA` in Fragments since I already extend my Fragment activity with `Fragment`?

Comment: And what prevents you from extending Application class?

Comment: I am already extending my fragments with Fragment (FragmenName extends Fragment). I will add this info to my initial message as well.

Answer (score 0):

ACRA listens to unhandled unchecked Exceptions in your application. If one is thrown (from *ANY* class Activity, Fragment, anything) it captures that error and sends it to your error reporting server.

To add ACRA to your project you need to have an Application class. Ie extend `android.app.Application` and initialise ACRA in it. This is the same whether you are using Fragments or not.

Comment: so if I extend my activity with Fragment, ACRA should still work ?

Comment: In a pure Java sense you **cannot** extend your `Activity` with a `Fragment`, they are entirely different classes. You can use Fragments within your Activities - this is a good practice. And you can still use ACRA.